# Laravel 5 View need to be get functioned properly

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, view

I`m new to the laravel 5.4.so that i need to get fixed this problem.

i`m working on attendance management system for my company.for the purpose of filtered trainees i developed search controller function like this .

```
 public function search_code(Request $request){
    $query = $request->search;
    $queryType = $request->institute; // 'id' or 'name'
    $items = DB::table('registerdetails');        

    if($queryType == 'id'){
      $items = $items->where('trainee_id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    if($queryType == 'full_name'){
      $items = $items->where('full_name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
   $items = $items->get();

    return view('traineeattendance.index')->with('items',$items);

            }
```

So that see it`s appearance.[image]

as you can see this returns all the value under the search function.this is on index.blade.php.

Then After doing search it gets filtered.then i press Add attendance button on right side.so that Add attendance form`s first  fields need to be get filled according to search result automatically.that means Trainee_Id.see this image.

[image]

So that this is Add Attendance form view called attendance.blade.php.

```
  <form action="{{route('TraineeAttendance.store')}}" method="post" >
       {{ csrf_field() }} 
       &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;

    <div class="form-group">

    <label>Trainee ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value="MOB/TR/">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label >Starting Time</label>       
            <input class="form-control" type="time" value="" id="example-time-input" name="starting_time">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
            <label >End Time</label>        
            <input class="form-control" type="time" value="" id="example-time-input" name="end_time">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
            <label >Site Visit Time</label>     
            <input class="form-control" type="time" value="" id="example-time-input" name="site_visit_time">
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Are you using a certain js library like jQuery?

Comment: No sir,just only laravel and html

Comment: You need search and for every search result you have to add attendance ? Am I right ?

Comment: lets say like this .i searched training id MOB/TR/1741 then press search button.it gives filtered value.for that i need to add attendance.as i above show add attendance forms first field need to be auto filled

Comment: When you add attendance for one of the search result then you need MOB/TR/1741 at input field automatically ?

Comment: Yes sir.but not using jQery library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS:

You can retrieved the value of each `values` you needed, (e.g Trainee ID) by using the `this` context on `onclick` event listener.

Assuming that you've set your `html` attendance list like this

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td class="trainee-id"> MOB/TR/Sample 1 </td>
       <td> Sample Training 1 </td>
       <td> 2001-12-12 </td>
       <td> 2001-12-13 </td>
       <td><a href="#" class="add-attendance" onclick="getTraineeId(this)"> Add Attendance </a></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td class="trainee-id"> MOB/TR/Sample 2 </td>
       <td> Sample Training 2 </td>
       <td> 2001-12-14 </td>
       <td> 2001-12-15 </td>
       <td><a href="#" class="add-attendance" onclick="getTraineeId(this)"> Add Attendance </a></td>
   </tr>

</tbody>
```

Then for your JS, You can get the value like this:

```
<script> 

function getAttendance(oElement) {
    console.log(oElement) // The DOM Element (e.g add-attendance)
    var sValue = oElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('trainee-id')[0].value; // Sample value you will get = MOB/TR/Sample 1
}

 </script>
```

Then on your [form] as given above, Try to place an [id] in your [Trainee ID] input field:

```
<label>Trainee ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control"  id="input-trainee-id" value="MOB/TR/">
</div>
```

From which you can place the value you get earlier and assign it in your [Trainee ID] input field

```
<script> 

function getAttendance(oElement) {
    console.log(oElement) // The DOM Element (e.g add-attendance)
    var sValue = oElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('trainee-id')[0].value; // Sample value you will get = MOB/TR/Sample 1
}

 document.getElementById('input-trainee-id').value = sValue;

 </script>
```

You can also apply it to your other fields (e.g Name / Starting Time / End Time) as well. Hope this will guide you well.